# I don't get "add button" with inline create on Backpack Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-backpack

Following this documentation : https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/4.1/crud-operation-inline-create
I try to create a link between invoices (primary) and invoices lines (secondary).
The link seems good, but I don't succeed to have the "+add" button needed to have the secondary form.
[image: result of my code]

My code.

Primary class (invoiceCrudController)

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use App\Models\Invoice;
use Backpack\CRUD\app\Http\Controllers\CrudController;

/**
 * Class InvoiceCrudController
 * @package App\Http\Controllers\Admin
 * @property-read \Backpack\CRUD\app\Library\CrudPanel\CrudPanel $crud
 */
class InvoiceCrudController extends CrudController
{
    use \Backpack\CRUD\app\Http\Controllers\Operations\ListOperation;
    use \Backpack\CRUD\app\Http\Controllers\Operations\CreateOperation;
    use \Backpack\CRUD\app\Http\Controllers\Operations\UpdateOperation;
    use \Backpack\CRUD\app\Http\Controllers\Operations\ShowOperation;
    use SetAccesses;
    
    protected function setupCreateOperation()
    {
        $this->crud->setValidation(InvoiceRequest::class);

        $this->crud->addFields([
            /*other cases*/
            [
                'name' => 'invoiceLines',
                'type' => 'relationship',
                'tags'=> 'invoice lines',
                'ajax'=>true,
                [ // specify the entity in singular
                    'entity' => 'invoiceLine', // the entity in singular
                ]
            ],

        ]);
    }

    protected function setupUpdateOperation()
    {
        $this->setupCreateOperation();
    }
}
```

secondary class (invoiceLinesController)

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use App\Models\InvoiceLine;
use Backpack\CRUD\app\Http\Controllers\CrudController;

/**
 * Class InvoiceCrudController
 * @package App\Http\Controllers\Admin
 * @property-read \Backpack\CRUD\app\Library\CrudPanel\CrudPanel $crud
 */
class InvoiceLinesCrudController extends CrudController
{
    use \Backpack\CRUD\app\Http\Controllers\Operations\CreateOperation;
    use \Backpack\CRUD\app\Http\Controllers\Operations\InlineCreateOperation;

    public function setup()
    {
        $this->setAccesses('invoiceLine');
        $this->crud->setModel('App\Models\InvoiceLine');
        $this->crud->setRoute(config('backpack.base.route_prefix') . '/invoiceLine');
        $this->crud->setEntityNameStrings('invoiceLine', 'invoiceLines');

        $this->crud->addColumns([
            [
                'name' => 'slug',
                'type' => 'text',
            ],
            [
                'name' => 'quantity',
                'type' => 'number',
                'default' => 1,
                'wrapper' => [
                    'class' => 'form-group col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-3 col-xl-3'
                ]
            ],
            [
                'name' =>'unit_vat_excluded',
                'type' => 'text',
                'wrapper' => [
                    'class' => 'form-group col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-3 col-xl-3'
                ]
            ]
        ]);
    }

    protected function setupListOperation()
    {
        $this->crud->enableExportButtons();

        CustomerCrudController::addFilterCustomer();
    }

    protected function setupCreateOperation()
    {
        $this->crud->addFields([
            [
                'name' => 'slug',
                'type' => 'text',
                'allows_null' => false,
            ],
            [
                'name' => 'quantity',
                'type' => 'number',
                'default' => 1,
                'wrapper' => [
                    'class' => 'form-group col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-3 col-xl-3'
                ]
            ],
            [
                'name' =>'unit_vat_excluded',
                'type' => 'text',
                'wrapper' => [
                    'class' => 'form-group col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-3 col-xl-3'
                ]
            ]
        ]);
    }

    protected function setupUpdateOperation()
    {
        $this->setupCreateOperation();
    }

    protected function setupShowOperation()
    {

    }

    public static function getColumn()
    {
        return [
            'name' => 'invoice_line_id',
            'label' => 'InvoiceLines',
            'type' => 'select',
            'entity' => 'invoiceLine',
            'attribute' => 'pretty_print',
            'model' => InvoiceLine::class,
        ];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the wrong is in your Filed definistion:

> $this->crud->addFields([
> /*other cases*/
> [
> 'name' => 'invoiceLines',
> 'type' => 'relationship',
> 'tags'=> 'invoice lines',
> 'ajax'=>true,
> [ // specify the entity in singular
> 'entity' => 'invoiceLine', // the entity in singular
> ]
> ],

since the relation is on to many (I guess) then the filed should be:

```
[
    'type' => "relationship",
    'name' => 'invoiceLines', 
    'ajax' => true,
    'inline_create' => true, 
]
```